# Minikube Virtualbox Save-state/restart node

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

I am using Minikube with Virtualbox for my home labs and that's awesome.
But sometime I would like to simulate crashe node (Just reset or shutdown VM) or just I don't need this cluster now (Suspend all VMs).
But there is a problem, after any of action reboot VM or suspend VM - minikube doesn't start internal services.
Did anybody have explanation of this behavior and could advice how to avoid it? (Just I don't want to prepare manually VMs, deploy K8s etc.)
PS
When VM up after restart/shutdown/wake up - there is no docker/containerd services start automatically.

Reboot VM, Save State VM and resume.
My expectations are kubernetes cluster works fine but it is not.

PS
Some update: Save-state is ok related to services, but by some reason I lost access via network to node -(

Comment: How do you stop/start the machine?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, more details: I just make "save-state" for example any of node and up it again and it is completly lost connection to my host. It's ok after reboot but after reboot no services related to kubernetes is started.

Comment: There is no safe-state minikube command.

Comment: You need to set the configuration minikube config to run minikube start.

Comment: Hi everyone thank for helping. I dropped it and just deployed it via vagrant the cluster which I need. Minikube is not appropriate but it is good solution for fast testing.